# Searching particular string in a string array of split operations

Tags: java

I have a string

```
str = "Abc=1,gdf=1,ghj=1,pqr=1"
```

Now I to increment the value of pqr=1 to pqr2 whenever prq will come it will increment the value by 1.  So I decided to start by Spitting this string at every ","  so that a part of spilited string array will contain pqr=1 and then I can perform my operation of incrementing.

Code is as follows

```
String []  parts=str.split("=");
```

This gives parts of string which contains pqr at index 3 but it is not necessary everytime pqr will be at index 3 so I want to make I it generic.  For that I am trying to do as follows:

```
if(Arrays. asList(parts). contains("pqr") {
    // Do my other split operation 
}
```

But I am not able to make it generic by this.  I am not getting any error but code is not going inside if statement.  Please suggest how to do it.

Comment: Take a look at guava `MapSplitter`, see https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Splitter.MapSplitter.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is not at all advisable to use `String` for this purpose. I think what you need is a `HashMap<String,Integer>` instead.

Moreover, you can simply iterate over your first array and check in every `String` for the `substring` `pqr`.

```
str = "Abc=1,gdf=1,ghj=1,pqr=1";
String[] arr = str.split(",");
for(String member: arr) {
    if(member.contains("pqr")) {
        //Do your operation here
    }
}
```

Comment: If conditions matches i. e member contains pqr then how can I get that part as string so that I can do further operations

Comment: `member` will be "that part of the string". You can simply break the loop and take it out of there (I am assuming there is just one occurence of `pqr` in the `String`)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? I am doing my best with the code provided.

```
    public class Splitter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "Abc=1,gdf=1,ghj=1,pqr=1";

        String[] strSplit = str.split(",");

        int commaSplitCount = strSplit.length;

        for (int s = 0; s < commaSplitCount; s++) {

            String[] sSplit = strSplit[s].split("=");

            int equalsSplitCount = sSplit.length;

            if (equalsSplitCount > 0) {

                for (int sParts = 0; sParts < equalsSplitCount; sParts++) {
                    if (sParts == 0) {
                        if (sSplit[sParts].contains("pqr")) {

                            System.out.println("do something >> " + sSplit[sParts]);

                        } else {
                            System.out.println("do something else >> " + sSplit[sParts]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

If you do something different with each, you can use a switch.

The output is:

```
do something else >> Abc
do something else >> gdf
do something else >> ghj
do something >> pqr
```

Whatever it is you want to do to pqr you can do at the sout so something.

Comment: If conditions matches i. e member contains pqr then how can I get that part as string so that I can do further operations

Comment: In my example when you get into the nested for loop, you would have the variable name as "sSplit[0]" and the value for that variable would be "sSplit[1]". The iterator is "sParts" in the area where it contains "pqr" you could Integer.parseInt(sSplit[sParts + 1]). Then you can do whatever you want to that number.

Comment: Did you get this figured out? Hope everything worked out for you.